# Commonality of specific romantic phrases in Italian

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, idioms, phrase-choice

I was talking to my Italian professoressa and we were basically discussing how couples in Italy interact. Raised in Italy, she insisted that the phrase `Ti amo` is actually very uncommon in Italy and that people do not really say that specific phrase out loud.

When I questioned an Italian friend for an alternative, he emphasized upon the commonality of the phrase `Ti voglio bene` while another friend said he has heard the phrase `Il mio amore per te è forte.`

With Italy being a very romantic country, along with Italian being a Romance language, I know there must be plenty of ways to express love. Thus, what I want to figure out is, *what is the most universally accepted way to infer the phrase **I love you** in Italian?*

Comment: Probably what your teacher meant is that the verb *amare* is used in Italian in far less situations than “to love” in English. The former is strictly used for serious romantic relationships, while the latter, I believe, may be used also for relatives (and perhaps even best friends?). *Ti voglio bene* is more usual in these cases (and a bit friendzoning between potential romantic partners). *Il mio amore per te è forte*, on the other hand, while grammatically correct is not a standard phrase, but one of many possible nice things one might want to say.

Comment: @DaG Just a minor note: while it's true that _Ti amo_ is strictly used for serious romantic relationships, the verb _amare_ in general is commonly used also for a few other types of close relationships, f.ex. it would be very normal to hear _La mamma ama i suoi figli_.

Comment: Jeffrey's answer is a very good explanation. _Ti amo_ is more like _I'm in love with you_. For friends and family we use _Ti voglio bene_. A couple in a relationship would use _Ti amo_, unless they are at the very beginning and are not that committed yet.

Comment: @SantiBailors: You're perfectly right, and there is even a (growing?) trend to use *amare* for more mundane objects, as in *Amo il mio lavoro* (I love my job), or a food, or a singer etc.

Comment: @DaG Good point, now that you mention that I realize that I too have noticed that growing trend; it's probably a reflection of the growing influence that English is having on Italian through the younger generations.

Comment: I'd like to stress out that *Ti amo*, if serious, should never be used lightly. You cannot say it while leaving for work, or while doing something else or just across a square, a special closeness to the partner must be created in order to avoid sounding deceiving IMO. It can be used for joking between intimates though. I heard a lot of female teens saying "Hey, ti ho <put a prank here>!" "S..nza!" "ahaha, ...ti amo!". Also keep in mind that habits vary a lot across Italy, so much that Italians have troubles their selves.

Comment: _"she insisted that the phrase Ti amo is actually very uncommon in Italy"_ _Amo_ la infondatezza di questa asserzione.

Comment: Different ages and different areas of Italy would have different attitudes towards the "ti amo". For what's worth, you have to consider the difference between "ti amo" and "ti voglio bene" a bit as the same difference that there is between "Im **in love** with u" and "I love you", even in English saying "in love with u" is much less common than "love you"... The teacher I had in high school, back in the day, used to say that out of context and put it in order of strenght was: being in love > loving > being fond of > liking

Comment: I dont know what kids do these days, probably they type it on facebook, but we used not only to say it in public but also to spray paint it on the walls

Comment: @SantiBailors I agree, it may be due to the growing influence of English on Italian but, in my opinion, a distinction must be made. If you say *Amo il mio lavoro*, it should be clear that the verb 'amare' takes a figurative meaning, because you cannot have a romantic relationship with your job. However, when 'love' refers to a person, the meaning becomes more unclear, and that's why Italians tend to use two different phrases, *ti voglio bene* or *ti amo*. Such a distinction existed also in Latin, see Catullus 72 and the difference between *amare* (*amare*) and *bene velle* (*volere bene*).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I use `ti amo` a lot, even with additions that intensify the claim. However, it isn't the exact translation of `I love you` de facto, as it is a real intense claim. `Ti voglio bene` is a claim you could use more often and even in public joking with your friends, when your partner says some harsh remark that really makes you proud, for example.

DaG accurately explained that you can use `ti voglio bene` for relatives and intimate friends as well, while `il mio amore per te è forte` is a sentence you'll never hear. You'll probably find it in a grammar book as an example, as it is very unnatural and forced.

I wanted to add the precise meaning of the two expressions. Even if both things are translated to `I love you` in English, `ti voglio bene` means you feel for that person, hope the best for him/her and feel really sorry when something bad happens to him/her. It's like an empathic issue. `Ti amo` adds, to a more intense version of all this, most probably a physical attraction as well, and very likely a sexual desire. It is, again, something you would say to your partner when looking him/her intensely straight in the eyes, before kissing him/her, or when making peace after a minor, or even intense, bicker, to remind that despite some little differences you may have, way bigger feelings unite the two of you, and those can't be mined by tiny things.

Finally, `il mio amore per te è forte` translates to "my love to you is strong". How natural is it in English?

Comment: If one was confessing their love for another person for the first time, would  he or she still use `ti voglio bene` or is it justified to use `ti amo`

Comment: I think `ti amo` would be more appropriated, even if a little bit cliched. Being `ti voglio bene` less intense, I feel like using it to confess one's feelings for the first time would lead to the receiver not fully understanding them, and taking it more as an affection than true love.

Answer (score 3):

She's right, at least for my generation (currently aged 40). `Ti amo` is too strong and too ruined by thousands of movies. Like eating too much sugar makes you tired of it. In fact, to an Italian it would sound fake even in a context when you actually mean it.

We use more elaborate phrasings, like `ti voglio bene` but not only (it's really the most basic one), or funny nicknames, to convey our affection. For example, we tend to use possessive, like `sei il mio amore`, or `sei la mia stella`

Comment: Benvenuto su Italian.SE!